# Any suggested solution for java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xdb.XMLType incompatible with oracle.sql.OPAQUE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, websphere-liberty, xmltype

I am setting up Liberty server I have added on below 4 features

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

and connecting to oracle it is working fine in my windows machine not on client's linux machine.

```
Error while retrieving record.
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xdb.XMLType incompatible with oracle.sql.OPAQUE
```

I have copied the same set of 3 jars into client machine still no luck

ojdbc8.jar
xdb6.jar
xmlparserv2_sans_jaxp_services.jar

Oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the 3 jars, if oracle.sql.OPAQUE.class is defined in more than one of them, in which case, one of those may be at a compatible version and the other not.  In the different environments, you may be getting a different precedence in which one is loaded.  If that's the case, the solution will be to get copies of JARs that are all at the same/compatible level.